# Find faces in a JUNG graph

Tags: java, jung2

How to find faces, or more specifically, sets of edges of the same face, in a JUNG graph?

Found functions and it provides something like find incident edges, find neighbors, but it does not help. Is there a proper way to find faces in a network graph, using the functions provided?

Answer (score 0):

JUNG is designed for general graphs, not just for planar graphs, and in order for the concept of "faces" of a graph to be well-defined, the graph must be planar.

Up to this point, no one has requested methods for either (1) determining whether  a graph is planar or (2) identifying faces in a planar graph.

Your best bet is likely to implement these capabilities yourself using JUNG's graph model:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarity_testing
2. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23811/reporting-all-faces-in-a-planar-graph